# Ag grid tool open all by default

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

Ag grid tool open all by default.
Hey I am New To Ag Grid. 
I did grouping in that want to show all the tool panels open by default

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll want to set the groupDefaultExpanded property on each group/panel.

http://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-grouping/index.php